OpenCV: pixel-accurate rendering
I'm having this code on my Raspberry Pi5:
import cv2
import numpy as np

box_size = (640, 480)
spacing = 1
num_rectangles = 4

window_width = 640
window_height = 1200

frame = np.ones((window_height, window_width, 3), dtype=np.uint8) * 255

def draw_rectangles():
    frame[:] = 255
    for i in range(num_rectangles):
        top_left_y = i * (box_size[1] + spacing)
        bottom_right_y = top_left_y + box_size[1]
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (0, top_left_y), (box_size[0], bottom_right_y), (0, 0, 0), 1)

cv2.namedWindow('Rectangles', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow('Rectangles', window_width, window_height)

while True:
    draw_rectangles()
    cv2.imshow('Rectangles', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()

There is a problem with the pixel-accurate display: there should be a pixel distance between the rectangles as defined by spacing=1, but they are stuck directly to each other.
Iis it due to the screen resolution or how can a pixel-accurate display be achieved?

The parameters of cv2.rectangle :
image = cv2.rectangle(image, start_point, end_point, color, thickness)

Consider adding the thickness of the line the rectangle is drawn with to the distance when calculating the position of the next rectangle.  Perhaps changing the code from this:
def draw_rectangles():
    frame[:] = 255
    for i in range(num_rectangles):
        top_left_y = i * (box_size[1] + spacing)
        bottom_right_y = top_left_y + box_size[1]
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (0, top_left_y), (box_size[0], bottom_right_y), (0, 0, 0), 1)

To this:
def draw_rectangles():
    frame[:] = 255
    thickness = 1
    for i in range(num_rectangles):
        top_left_y = i * (box_size[1] + spacing + thickness)
        bottom_right_y = top_left_y + box_size[1]
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (0, top_left_y), (box_size[0], bottom_right_y), (0, 0, 0), thickness)

May help.
